# installed nextcloud, apps/dashboard/index.php file missing

Tags: php, nginx, nextcloud

I have installed nextcloud 26.0.10 on ubuntu running nginx.  When I first hit the URL it gave me a window to set up an admin username and password, specify the data folder location and the database location as expected.

First time I submitted the wrong password and it griped at me, so I know the second time the config setup went fine, but then it redirected me to `mydomain.com/index.php/apps/dashboard`

which gave an Ngnix `403 Forbidden` error

Trying to change the URL to:

`mydomain.com/apps/dashboard`

also gives the same `403`, and there are no files in that directory like an index.php, just subfolders.

Anyone know what might be wrong here?  I have not seen this in the NC docs so far.

(HINT: I suspect this is an issue with routing redirects, which I'm familiar with in Apache but not nginx)

Comment: Your rewriting setup does not work.

Comment: And, just asking ... why version 26.0.10? That is far outdated ...

Comment: @arkascha yes, I'm looking for that code for the mod_rewrite equivalent and will post as an answer when I find it :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

The following seems to be a partial answer but it's not complete.  This will allow `mydomain.com/index.php/apps/dashboard` to display, but `mydomain.com/apps/dashboard` (the pretty URL) will still produce a 403 (because there is a folder path but no actual index.php file there, and shouldn't be):

```
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?args;
        }
```

Comment: I use `index index.php index.html /index.php$request_uri;` and `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri;`... It allows me to use the short URL without embedded `index.php`, _but_ the system itself forwards to the URL with that `index.php` ...